# QtableView sortingEnabled and column selection

Tags: python, select, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel, pyside6

I use a QtableView in PySide 6,  populated by QSortFilterProxyModel, and setSortingEnabled is true, so I can sort by column.
But by doing this, I'm no more able to select the column by clicking the header.

The idea is to be able to sort the column by clicking on the arrow icon and to select the column by clicking on the text for instance.

Answer (score 2):

When the sortingEnabled property is enabled, the sectionPressed signal of the selectColumn slot is disconnected, so a possible solution is to reconnect it:

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel
from PySide6.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView


def main():
    app = QApplication()

    model = QStandardItemModel(10, 4)
    for i in range(model.rowCount()):
        for j in range(model.columnCount()):
            item = QStandardItem(f"item {i}x{j}")
            model.setItem(i, j, item)

    proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
    proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)

    view = QTableView()
    view.setSortingEnabled(True)
    view.setModel(proxy_model)
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    view.horizontalHeader().sectionPressed.connect(view.selectColumn)

    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Since the OP wants it to only be ordered when the indicator is pressed, then it is necessary to prevent the order indicator from changing state when it is pressed outside.

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QSortFilterProxyModel, Qt
from PySide6.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHeaderView, QTableView


class HorizontalHeader(QHeaderView):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.new_order = self.sortIndicatorOrder()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        height = self.height()
        x = event.position().x()
        logical_index = self.logicalIndexAt(x)
        x_left = self.sectionPosition(logical_index)
        x_right = x_left + self.sectionSize(logical_index)
        if (x_right - height) <= x <= x_right:
            self.new_order = (
                Qt.DescendingOrder
                if self.new_order == Qt.AscendingOrder
                else Qt.AscendingOrder
            )

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)
        x = event.position().x()
        logical_index = self.logicalIndexAt(x)
        self.setSortIndicator(logical_index, self.new_order)


def main():
    app = QApplication()
    app.setStyle("fusion")

    model = QStandardItemModel(10, 4)
    for i in range(model.rowCount()):
        for j in range(model.columnCount()):
            item = QStandardItem(f"item {i}x{j}")
            model.setItem(i, j, item)

    proxy_model = QSortFilterProxyModel()
    proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)

    view = QTableView()
    horizontal_header = HorizontalHeader(Qt.Horizontal)
    view.setHorizontalHeader(horizontal_header)
    horizontal_header.setSortIndicatorShown(True)
    horizontal_header.setSectionsClickable(True)
    view.setModel(proxy_model)
    horizontal_header.sortIndicatorChanged.connect(proxy_model.sort)
    horizontal_header.setSortIndicator(0, Qt.AscendingOrder)
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Very nice, the column is selectable with this but is also sorted as soon as I click on the header. 
Is it possible to limit the sort when clicking on the arrow icon, or may be another solution could be to not use the proxymodel and implement a sort by right clicking on the header of the column ?

Comment: @EricRV try with the new solution

Comment: yes it works well. 
There was no header in your code, so I add header data (model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Serial Number"  ) and yes, it's perfect !